# Detecting Circles within an image

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm currently using EmguCV to run shape detection on an image of a shooting range target: [image]

But no matter my settings in the code (below):

`double cannyThreshold = 180;
double circleAccumulatorThreshold = 170;
CircleF[] circles = CvInvoke.HoughCircles(uimage, HoughType.Gradient, 2.0, 1.0, cannyThreshold, circleAccumulatorThreshold, 5);`

I can only seem to find three circles, of which one is wrong.
[image]

Am I going about this incorrectly? I'm using the default example for shape detection included with [Rev3.0 EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp).

Comment: Houghcircles won't find concentric circles.

Comment: So what will find concentric circles

Comment: You can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32287930/5008845) to get the idea...

Answer (score 2):

1. Find edges first (see Sobel operator or Canny for example)
2. Find contours, after that contours will represent circles
3. Filter contours by area
4. Use minEnclosingCircle for each contour to get center and
   radius.