# hough circle does not find any circle

Tags: qt, opencv, hough-transform

I use this code to find circles in below image. but it does not find any circle. what is the problem with it?

```
 vector<Vec3f> AllCircles;
 HoughCircles( img, AllCircles,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,1, 180, 100, 0,0 );
```

[image]

Comment: reduce the threshold from 180 to 50 or sth. since your gray vs black  might not produce gradients as strong as white vs black.

Comment: You also can't find concentric circles with HoughCircles

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190594/detecting-circles-within-an-image/34194542#34194542