# Contour Arrays in OpenCV

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

In another user's post, they discussed how they were having trouble using OpenCV's Hough Circle Transform to detect and draw over each ring on a bull target [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287032/circular-hough-transform-misses-circles). A proposed solution was to instead using contours to locate each circle. When I attempted the same thing, my result was exactly what I was looking for; the only problem is that the program I'm attempting to create needs a series of circles, one on each ring, so that I may then calculate the distance from the center and therefore the particular ring where a given point exists.

Following the code if the mentioned post, I have the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('bull.png')
image_copy = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
grayscaled_image = cv2.cvtColor(image_copy, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

cv2.imshow("confirm", grayscaled_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

_,contours,_  = cv2.findContours(255 - image_copy, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print(contours)

cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, color=(0,255,0), thickness=1)

cv2.imshow("detected circles", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Which gives me the same results as shown in the linked post.

And this is great. I love the progress. However, I initially tried using the same method that the linked poster did because I liked the coordinate and radius information provided by the circles.

I found in one of [OpenCV's tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html#gsc.tab=0) that you can contain a contour with a circle, rectangle, or ellipse. The tutorial is rather easy to follow for an individual contour, but in my code, I have no idea what `_,contours,_` means. Is it some sort of array? How do I access the individual contours? When I tried printing the variable, it gave me close to 4,000 lines. I won't post them here, of course, but they appeared to be sets of coordinates.

So my question is: How can I go about converting this grouping of contours into more manageable circles?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in your previous question you can use [minEnclosingCircle](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle) on each contour. and you'll get circles centers and radiuses.